# Getting Context into Test Classes with Junit5

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, android-testing, junit5

We're using the Junit 5 framework for unit testing in your Android project. How can I get context into these test classes?

Used Plugin; https://github.com/mannodermaus/android-junit5

Comment: Have you considered using Roboelectric?

Comment: How? Can you explain? @Jaime

Answer (score 0):

For now I found this solution. Method parameterization invokes extra code, but resolves my case.

Your test class should have extension `@ExtendWith(MyExtension.class)`
For example,

```
@ExtendWith(MyExtension.class)
public class MyTestScript {
    // tests
}
```

Extension class should implement `ParameterResolver` interface, like bellow:

```
public class MyExtension implements ParameterResolver {
    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(ParameterContext parameterContext, ExtensionContext extensionContext)
            throws ParameterResolutionException {
        return true; // if you supports parameters in the test class
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveParameter(ParameterContext parameterContext, ExtensionContext extensionContext)
            throws ParameterResolutionException {
        return extensionContext; // includes context which can be used in the test script
    }
```

So, in the test script you should parameterize all methods where you want to use `context`:

```
@ExtendWith(MyExtension.class)
public class MyTestScript {
    @BeforeAll
    void beforeAll(ExtensionContext context) {
        logger.logInfo(context, "BeforeAll execution");    }

    @AfterAll
    void afterAll(ExtensionContext context) {
        logger.logInfo(context, "AfterAll execution");
    }

    @BeforeEach
    void beforeEach(ExtensionContext context) {
        logger.logInfo(context, "BeforeEach execution");
    }

    @AfterEach
    void afterEach(ExtensionContext context) throws InterruptedException {
        logger.logInfo(context, "AfterEach execution");
    }

    @Test
    void exampleTest(ExtensionContext context) {
        logger.logInfo(context, "Test execution");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can get context using [Roboelectric](http://robolectric.org/)

```
// build.gradle
testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.3'
testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.0.0'
```

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class ContextTest {

  @Test
  public void getContextTest() {
    Context c = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()
    ...
  }

}
```

Comment: We should call this as unit test? Or, is this an instrumentation test?

Comment: Since @RunWith is used it’s definitely not JUnit 5 but JUnit 4.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions? @johanneslink

Comment: @CaferMertCeyhan https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/3477 suggests that JUnit 5 support for Roboelectric is on hold. You can still use JUnit 4 on the JUnit 5 platform with junit-vintage-engine: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#migrating-from-junit4-running

Comment: Downvoted because OP is asking for JUnit 5, not for Roboelectric. Many testing frameworks give contexts, but the question is only for JUnit 5.